# Mantener viva la conexión MySQL en Java

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo problemas con una aplicación que estoy haciendo en Java.

La aplicación se conecta a una base de datos MySQL remota y funciona perfecto, pero si dejo un rato inactiva la aplicación, después si quiero hacer algo se demora unos 10 segundo en responder.

Eso se debe a que se vuelve a conectar con la base de datos parece.

¿Hay alguna forma de dejar la conexión permanente activa o cambiar ese temporizador que hace que se desconecte?.

Comment: ¿Usas un pool de conexiones o todas las conexiones las abres inocentenemente con `DriverManager#getConnection`?

Answer (score 1):

## Problema

El problema está en que en algún punto de la conexión (tu equipo, el servidor o algún cortafuegos intermedio) da por finalizada por expiración la conexión TCP, filtrando los siguientes paquetes y provocando que el cliente tarde un tiempo en darse cuenta que el servidor no responde.

## Solución `tcpKeepAlive`

Para evitarlo usa el parámetro JDBC [`tcpKeepAlive`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) que proporciona MySQL para ayudar a "mantener viva" la conexión TCP.

```
jdbc:mysql//servidor=(tcpKeepAlive=true)/bbdd
```

Hay muchos parámetros más que podrían interesarte revisar:

- connectTimeout: Tiempo de espera para el establecimiento de conexión (en milisegundos), siendo 0 sin límite.
- socketTimeout: Tiempo de expiración de una operación con el socket.
- interactiveClient: Indica al servidor si debe usar el tiempo de expiración de espera normal ([`wait_timeout`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout)) o de clientes interactivos ([`interactive_timeout`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout)).

Éste último no soluciona ningún problema de timeout de los que sufres porque los valores por defecto suelen estar muy altos (8 horas, 28800 segundos), por lo que sólo la solución `tcpKeepAlive` podrá ayudarte.

## Configuración Windows

Para cambiar la frecuencia de los "keep alive" en Windows debes modificar una entrada de registro (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957549.aspx):

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
Tipo: REG_DWORD
Rango: 0x1–0xFFFFFFFF ( milisegundos )
Por defecto: 0x6DDD00 ( 7.200.000 milisegundos = 2 horas )
```

## Configuración Linux

Para cambiar la frecuencia en Linux debes cambiar parámetros del sistema (http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html):

```
# sudo sysctl -a | grep ^net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 75
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 9
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 7200
```

## Solución por software

Otra solución alternativa es, mediante algún sistema de detección de conexión en uso o exclusión mutua para no interferir con una transacción u alguna consulta que acaba de realizarse, enviar consultas SQL nulas cada cierto intervalo.

Una consulta nula, por ejemplo, podría ser:

```
-- Funciona incluso sin seleccionar previamente una base de datos
SELECT 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con esto:

```
con.query('SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=28800')
con.query('SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=28800')
con.query('SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout=28800')
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726789/how-can-i-change-the-default-mysql-connection-timeout-when-connecting-through-py